# NSDateFormatter Trouble?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I am trying to parse an RSS feed, but the date is hard to parse. The date string is: `publishedDate = "2013-01-08T20:09:02.000Z"`

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *dtUTC = [utc dateFromString: publishedDate];

NSDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:dtUTC];
NSLog(@"original UTC %@  now local: %@", dtUTC, time);
```

Why is `date` returning nil? Also, i am trying to convert UTC time to CST Time.

Comment: What is `publishedDate`?

Comment: a string...2013-01-08T20:09:02.000Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 [utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'000Z'"];
```

Comment: it still gives me the same 01

Comment: Hey, do you know if there is a way to parse an html link in an xml file? this is the code in the xml...<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XzhvczNjZDFuNmNzamFiOW02NTMzNGI5azhoMms0YjlwOGdvajBiOXA2NHJrNGNwazg5MjRhZzltNnMgbGF1cmVsY2hyaXN0aWFuc2Nob29sQG0' title='alternate'/>

Comment: you should ask a different question. That will help others looking for solution to similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

For stime that includes miliseconds use "S".

```
[utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'Z'"];

NSString *publishedDate = @"2013-01-08T20:09:02.000Z";
NSDateFormatter *utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *dtUTC = [utc dateFromString: publishedDate];
NSLog(@"dtUTC: %@", dtUTC);
```

NSLog output:
dtUTC: 2013-01-08 20:09:02 +0000

```
SDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:dtUTC];
NSLog(@"original UTC %@  now local: %@", dtUTC, time);
```

NSLog output:
original UTC 2013-02-08 20:09:02 +0000  now local: 2013-02-08

Answer (score 1):

Just change your time zone name to CST and change the setDateFormat as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *cst = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [cst setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"]];
    [cst setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'000Z'"];
    NSDate *theCST = [cst dateFromString:publishedDate];
    NSLog(@"theCST is %@", theCST);
```