# Objective C : Format standard Pubdate in rssfeed for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wordpress

I have an iOS  RSS feed app for, it's used XML parser to show the title and date, the problem is with the date, it uses this method :

```
if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{
    [title appendString:string];
} 
else if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) 
{
    [date appendString:string];
    
}
```

In my ViewController I used this method to show date :
I used UILabe called rssdate and I used this method

```
rssDate.text = [
    [self.parseResultsobjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pubDate"
];
[cell.contentView addSubview:rssDate];`
```

but the date is showing in this format :
@"Tue, 02 Apr 2013 18:54:26 +0000";

How I can change this format and set date format like this :
Date Label : @"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"

Comment: possible duplicate of [NsDateFormatter Trouble?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227585/nsdateformatter-trouble)

Comment: Thank you I saw your link, but this is not solve my issue, because in my parser xml it's use NSMutableString for date , and it's only work with [date appendString:string] , so it's give me same format : Tue, 02 Apr 2013 18:54:26 +0000 , even if try to add NSdateFormatter . So I am confuse

Answer (score 1):

Use a date formatter (see `NSDateFormatter`) to parse the date string into a date. Then use another date formatter to turn the date back into a string in the format you want.

Comment: Sorry -- I don't have time to write up an example, but there are quite a few questions already on SO that will show you how to use NSDateFormatter. I've voted to close this question as a duplicate -- if you look at the [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14227585/643383) question you'll find a great example of using a date formatter to parse a date from an RSS feed and then reformat the date with another formatter. Good luck.

Comment: the problem is with this : [date appendString:string];
I tried to use [date NSDateFormatter]; but have an error, and why you vote to close the question maybe another person can help also .

Comment: `[date NSDateFormatter]` doesn't make any sense. Take a look at the code in the linked question. The only problem with that code is that the date format string for the `utc` formatter is incorrect. The accepted answer provides a correct format string that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you I saw your link, but this is not solve my issue, because in my parser xml it's use NSMutableString for date , and it's only work with  [date appendString:string] , so it's give me same format : Tue, 02 Apr 2013 18:54:26 +0000 , even if try to add NSdateFormatter . So I am confuse .